# How to unblock a thread blocked on ServerSocket.accept()?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server thread with this code:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket server;
        EneaLog.printLog("Server is running.");
        server = new ServerSocket(this.portnumber);

        while (true) {
            new EneaServerConnection(server.accept(), this.project,stopped).start();
            if (stopped) {
                EneaLog.printLog("Server safe-shutdown completed.");
                EneaLog.printLog("Hi!");
                server.close();
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EneaServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        project.getExceptionHandler().handler(ex);
    }
}
```

and a shutdown method like this:

```
public void shutdown() {
    EneaLog.printLog("Server shutdown NOW!");
    stopped = true;
}
```

I want that shutdown can unblock thread that are waiting on server.accept() otherwise I must wait for connection before server shutdown.

I can't do server.close() in shutdown() because I must signal to registered client that server is coming down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to design my code so that it can be "shutdown" with an interrupt. Mainly, this is because the `Executor` framework in Java's concurrency package uses `interrupt` to cancel running tasks. Also, the "shutdown" task doesn't have to know any internals of the task being killed.

However, a call to `accept` will not respond to an interrupt *unless* it is [created from a `ServerSocketChannel`.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html#socket()) A server created with a `ServerSocket` constructor will ignore interrupts, and I haven't found a way to reconfigure this.

If you can't change the code that creates the server, arrange for another thread to call `close` on the server socket. This will also raise an exception in thread blocked on `accept`, regardless of the method used to create the server socket.

This turns out to be a really big pain when using SSL. A JSSE socket is not created from an `InterruptibleChannel`, and won't respond to a simple interrupt on the thread.

---

I just noticed that the question says that the server can't be closed without notifying the client. Successfully interrupting a socket results in its closure.

On a call to `accept` this shouldn't be a problem, since the client is not connected if the server socket is blocked in accept. That should only be an issue for `Socket` instances, that represent current connections.

If that doesn't satisfy the notification requirements, a rework to use NIO's `ServerSocketChannel` in non-blocking mode may be necessary.

Comment: mmm good answer.. Maybe I change approach to problem. I manage server shutdown in client-side with try-catch.

Comment: I wonder if you can have the server create another client socket from a separate thread and once the accept() unblocks it, the now unblocked loop can somehow immediately interrogate that client socket ..know it is its own client socket ... and set a flag to exit the endless loop. Never tried it but maybe something to think about

Comment: Possibly, but that sounds like you’d need the ability to modify the server code. If you have that, just use a `ServerSocketChannel`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to close the socket from another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Neither interrupt (that's dependent on interrupt points in the same way cancellation is dependent on cancellation points) nor close will do it (accept does not responsed to closing its file descriptor).  You'll have to communicate with the accept (try sendto, with a shutdown notification) to notify it to not continue accepting.  At least this is the case on linux; don't know what it's like on other platforms.

Comment: how do you solve this problem at last? 
many people say close will work, but it does not work in my case which run on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I've been faced to the same problem. My working solutions consists into closing the ServerSocket object (serverSocket.close()) ; doing this will cause the accept() method to throw a SocketException, which is what you want to do.

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Thread.interrupt()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) ?

> If this thread is blocked in an I/O
>   operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be
>   closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will
>   receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a
>   Selector then the thread's interrupt
>   status will be set and it will return
>   immediately from the selection
>   operation, possibly with a non-zero
>   value, just as if the selector's
>   wakeup method were invoked.

Comment: You need to call it on the thread you want to interrupt (i.e. the blocked one)