# Interrupting thread which is blocked waiting on IO from socket?

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I have an app that listens to incoming connections on a specified hostname and port. The listening is invoked with the method `listen()` (see below), which waits constantly for an incoming connection using `ServerSocket.accept()`, creating a new `Thread` to handle the input stream.

```
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private Thread listenerThread;

public void listen() throws IOException {
    this.listenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket socket = TheServerClass.this.serverSocket.accept();
                    // Create new thread to handle the incoming connection
                }
                catch (IOException exc) { }
            }
        }
    });
    this.listenerThread.start();
}
```

Now I want to stop the running of `listenerThread`. But when I call `this.listenerThread.interrupt()`, this doesn't work.
I thought you can stop a thread by interrupting it, so why isn't that working?

(**Notice:** A possible solution is to close the `ServerSocket` using `this.serverSocket.close()`, but can it be accomplished with `interrupt()` or something?)

Comment: As you point out, when using standard sockets, this is only possible by closing the socket. There are several questions here on SO dealing with same problem, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510403/how-to-unblock-a-thread-blocked-on-serversocket-accept

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Does it throw any exceptions? Or just continue usually?

Comment: @medopal The thread just continues running without terminating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `serverSocket.close()`,

I guess since you are not doing IO yet - you can not interrupt it, and since the `accept()` doesn't throw InterruptedException you won't be able to interrupt it. The thread is interrupted, but that flag you have to check for yourself `Thread.isInterrupted()`.

See [How can I interrupt a ServerSocket accept() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method).

Comment: Since `accept()` can't be interrupted (which is a little bit weird in my opinion, but so be it), I suppose I have to use `close()`... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the question. You need to close the socket. It's done using `serverSocket.close()`. `Thread.interrupt()` doesn't care about sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private boolean stop;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public MyThread(ServerSocket ss) {
        this.serverSocket = ss;
        this.stop = false;
    }

    public void setStop() {
        this.stop = true;
        if (this.ss != null) {
            this.ss.close();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                // Create new thread to handle the incoming connection 
            }
            catch (IOException exc) { }
        }
    }
}
```

and from the `listen()` method just call `setStop()` method of the thread.

Comment: Not good. You should at least declare `stop` as volatile, otherwise the compiler may optimize it in such way, that different threads would see different values.