# Closing additional threads during ServerSocket.accept() in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, asynchronous

in my current project I'm using my smartphone as a server. The server is started when a special Card or Tag was detected via `NFC`. This is the part that works.

In order to achieve this I'm using an `AsyncTask` that gets started once the tag is scanned. The problem is now, that I am not able to stop the server when he is currently calling `ServerSocket.accept()`. Calling `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` does not stop the server while he is waiting for a connection request.

How would I go about this if I want to stop the server at some point?

Right now I'm quite clueless. My only idea was to set the timeout time for the serversocket resulting in a thrown exception. But that would mean polling `ServerSocket.accept()` which can't be the only way going about this? If it is, that would be a rather poor solution in my eyes...

Comment: Could show a snippet or 2 of relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that you can call close() on the ServerSocket from another thread, which will throw a SocketException in accept().

Another is to use the timeout that you were thinking about.

See the following posts for ideas on how to implement this :

[How can I interrupt a ServerSocket accept() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983835/how-can-i-interrupt-a-serversocket-accept-method)

[Java Stop Server Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804797/java-stop-server-thread)

[Close listening ServerSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120986/close-listening-serversocket)

[Stop a socket from listening on accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212096/stop-a-socket-from-listening-on-accept)

[How to unblock a thread blocked on ServerSocket.accept()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510403/how-to-unblock-a-thread-blocked-on-serversocket-accept)

Comment: when do you want to stop the server?  Will a fixed timeout work for you? Or do you want it to be based on a user interaction ?

Comment: It's based on user interaction and the application life cycle (server should not run while app is in the background). Your links already helped. =)

Comment: Another way is to set some 'terminate' boolean and then persuade the accept() to return by temporarily opening a connection from another thread.